# How to change automatic named parameter id on Rails route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

My route file have a definition to method finish:

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :disputes do
    resources :conferences, shallow: true do
      put :finish
    end
  end
end
```

Rails automatic put the param id with name `:conference_id`, but I wish use `:id` instead.

```
conference_finish PUT      /conferences/:conference_id/finish(.:format) disputes/conferences#finish {:format=>:json}
```

Have a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
put "conferences/:something/finish", to: "disputes/conferences#finish"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could improve Gabriel's answer by using **member** option according to [this guide's section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) (I don't know if it will work in your case):

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :disputes do
    resources :conferences, shallow: true do
      member do
        put :finish
      end          
    end
  end
end
```

You could also use one line way:

```
resources :disputes do
  scope module: :disputes do
    resources :conferences, shallow: true do
      put :finish, on: :member
    end
  end
end
```

With this you will have params[:id] in your controller. By the way, resources should never be nested more than 1 level deep. Look into [2.7.1 Limits to Nesting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)